# Can't access docker port from remote

Tags: docker, networking

I start a container on machine whose IP address is `47.foo.bar.bazz`:

```
docker run -it -p 8888:8888 continuumio/miniconda3
```

And inside the container ,`8888`port is opened by a flask application:

```
python manage.py runserver -h 0.0.0.0 -p 8888
```

I can send http request to this port successfully by

```
curl "http://127.0.0.1:8888/api/v1/vocabulary?callback=zoo
```

But when I use it's IP it doesn't work, and I can't access it from remote machine either

```
curl "http://47.foo.bar.bazz:8888/api/v1/vocabulary?callback=zoo
```

Here is some information:

```
netstat -aptn
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name  
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      9211/docker-proxy   
tcp6       0      0 :::8888                 :::*                    LISTEN      28811/docker-proxy  
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN      9194/docker-proxy
```

Btw,I can curl the `80` port successfully using the IP address.

Could anyone please point out what's wrong?How can I access it successfully from remote machine?

Comment: Can you show the output of `docker ps`?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out here. Maybe the port is blocked. On the other hand,I used nginx to forward my request form 80 to 8888.